# Flag the date when they return

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Story:**

For each id , they have a join date to a subscription and when they get rebilled **monthly**, they have a returning date. The first part of the exercise was to flag consecutive months of returned dates from the join date. Here's an example:

```
+----+------------+----------------+------+
| id | join_date  | returning_date | flag |
+----+------------+----------------+------+
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-01-01     |    1 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-02-01     |    1 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-03-01     |    1 |
+----+------------+----------------+------+
```

**Objective:**

What I would like to add is to flag those who return from a canceled subscription. That flag can be in another column. For example the following results shows that on May 1st 2019 , he returned. This date needs to be flagged:

```
+----+------------+----------------+------+
| id | join_date  | returning_date | flag |
+----+------------+----------------+------+
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-01-01     |    1 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-02-01     |    1 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-03-01     |    1 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-05-01     |    0 |
|  1 | 2018-12-01 | 2019-06-01     |    0 |
+----+------------+----------------+------+
```

**Fiddle Data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T1
create table #t1 (id int,join_date date, returning_date date)
insert into #t1 values
(1,'2018-12-01', '2019-01-01'),
(1,'2018-12-01', '2019-02-01'),
(1,'2018-12-01', '2019-03-01'),
(1,'2018-12-01', '2019-05-01'),
(1,'2018-12-01', '2019-06-01'),
(2,'2018-12-01', '2019-02-01'),
(2,'2018-12-01', '2019-03-01'),
(2,'2018-12-01', '2019-05-01'),
(2,'2018-12-01', '2019-06-01'),
(3,'2019-05-01', '2019-06-01'),
(3,'2019-05-01', '2019-08-01'),
(3,'2019-05-01', '2019-10-01')
```

**Current query with flag for consecutive months:**

```
select *
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,join_date,returning_date) = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY returning_date ASC) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
from #t1
ORDER BY ID,returning_date
```

Comment: What determines when someone returns from a cancelled subscription?  In other words, how do you know the subscription was cancelled?  I see a return date, but nothing that indicates return from cancellation....

Comment: @devlincarnate most recent non-consecutive month

Comment: @RogerSteinberg, shouldn't 2019-06-01 not be marked 0 then?

Comment: @pwilcox im assuming you mean for ID 1,2? Then yes its 0 because there were consecutive months, and then a break, which renders all future payments non consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you didn't specify which recurrence of returning as the target to flag, my query flags any non-consecutive date as a return date cause a subscriber could leave and return many times after their join date (the subscriber with [id] 3 technically returned in August and then again in October so that's returning twice but October is marked as LAST instead based on the data set). i also made it easier to read by adding in start date and end date based on the data set in your fiddle.

you can use this query as a temp table, cte, basis, or whatever to continue to query against if you need to manipulate the data further.

```
select a.*
    ,case
        when a.returning_date = (select min(c.returning_date) from subscription c where c.id = a.id and c.join_date = a.join_date) then 'START'
        when a.returning_date = (select max(c.returning_date) from subscription c where c.id = a.id and c.join_date = a.join_date) then 'END'
        when b.id is null then 'RETURN'
        else 'CONSECUTIVE'
    end as SubStatus
from subscription a
        left join subscription b on a.id = b.id and a.join_date = b.join_date and DATEADD(month,-1,a.returning_date) = b.returning_date
```

here is the result set from my query:

```
id          join_date  returning_date SubStatus
----------- ---------- -------------- -----------
1           2018-12-01 2019-01-01     START
1           2018-12-01 2019-02-01     CONSECUTIVE
1           2018-12-01 2019-03-01     CONSECUTIVE
1           2018-12-01 2019-05-01     RETURN
1           2018-12-01 2019-06-01     END
2           2018-12-01 2019-02-01     START
2           2018-12-01 2019-03-01     CONSECUTIVE
2           2018-12-01 2019-05-01     RETURN
2           2018-12-01 2019-06-01     END
3           2019-05-01 2019-06-01     START
3           2019-05-01 2019-08-01     RETURN
3           2019-05-01 2019-10-01     END
```

Comment: I absolutely love this structure. that was more than what I asked. Thank you !

Comment: glad we could add more to it. data is hard enough to work and manipulate with so if we can make it easier to read, then it's another win. good luck with it and keep on learning!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking if there are any gaps since an `id` first returned (with a given `join_date`).

If so, that is simply counting.  How many months since the first `return_date`?  How many rows?  Compare these to see if there are gaps:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when datediff(month, min(returning_date) over (partition by id, join_date order by returning_date), returning_date) <>
                  row_number() over (partition by id, join_date order by returning_date) - 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa120af448e937adc8fcf0bd8338486a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> flag consecutive months

and

> renders all future payments

are not phrases that are going to lead to a pretty query.  Which is why you had to resort to a while loop.  Nevertheless, what you seek is possible, and with work may prove more performant than your while loop for large data.  I present my sample code below using cte's, but you may want to use temp tables ore update an originally null 'flag' column on the base table.

In `flagNonConsecutive`, a flag is applied for any date that is not consecutive with the previous date (as identified using the `lag` window function) or by the join_date.

This meets the first requirement.  Then in `minNonConsecutives`, you identify the earliest of those flags for each id.

In the main query, any dates after the minimum get the 0 treatment:

```
with

    flagNonConsecutive as (

        select     *,
                   nonConsecutive = 
                       case 
                       when     datediff(month, join_date, returning_date) = 1 then 1
                       when     datediff(
                                    month,
                                    lag(returning_date) over(
                                         partition by id 
                                         order by returning_date
                                    ),
                                    returning_date
                                ) = 1 then 1
                       else     0
                       end
        from       @t1

    ),

    minNonConsecutives as (

        select    id,
                  minNonConsec = min(returning_date)
        from      flagNonConsecutive
        where     nonConsecutive = 0
        group by  id

    )

    select      fnc.id,
                fnc.join_date,
                fnc.returning_date,
                flag = iif(fnc.returning_date >= mnc.minNonConsec, 0, 1)
    from        flagNonConsecutive fnc
    left join   minNonConsecutives mnc on fnc.id = mnc.id;
```